# Python 2.7: "can't start new thread" error from "multiprocessing.Pool"

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Here's my situation. The code is almost the same as for the [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def grad(x0, y): return 0 # does some computational-heavy work actually

if __name__ == '__main__':

    class UnrollArgs:
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __call__(self, args):
            return self.func(*args)

    def batch_grad(x0, y, processes=4):
        g = Pool(processes).map(UnrollArgs(grad), [(x0, yi) for yi in y])
        return np.sum([gi for gi in g], axis=0) / len(y)
```

The `y` I pass to `batch_grad` has 50 elements and `Pool.map` throws an error:

> error: can't start new thread

From Google I know that this is usually caused by the fact that one is trying to start too many threads. Maybe it's just me, but I think the documentation on `multiprocessing.Pool` is a little incomplete. In particular, I don't get how to control the number of threads that should be started. The term "thread" isn't even mentioned in the documentation of the `Pool` class.

The integral argument to `multiprocessing.Pool` is the [number of *processes* to start](https://seattle.poly.edu/browser/seattle/trunk/dist/win/python/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py?rev=73#L83), not threads.

So how can I fix that?

**Update:** It might be worth noting that the error isn't raised *every* time I run the code.

Comment: I can't see anything in the code you posted that would lead to that error. Can you post a more complete example (one I can run)? Are you using `threading` elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @aganders3: This **is** my complete example, with the **only** exception that `grad` is doing some computational-heavy work. The error is raised from within of the `map` function of the `Pool` class. I'm **not** using `threading`.

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the pool and just use `map`? I can't get this error to reproduce on my system using your corrected code.

Comment: From the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Modules/_threadmodule.c#L1074) it seems to be a low level failure at creating threads in `PyThread_start_new_thread` (which is a wrapper around system dependent threading library), during Python interpreter start-up.  Maybe out-of-memory?

Comment: @aganders3: Yes, it does. Because **no** threads are spawned then. Please note my *update*, that the error doesn't raise *every* time I run the code.

Comment: @CongMa: Yes, it might be an out-of-memory. But still, how can I control (and maybe lower) the number of threads spawned per processes?

Comment: @theV0ID  I think this error was generated during the starting-up of Python interpreter itself when multiple interpreter processes get spawned by `multiprocessing`.  In this case you don't get control over how many number of real threads the interpreters start, at least not by `multiprocessing`.  But I may be wrong.  I'm not an expert in CPython internals.

Comment: @CongMa: Thanks very much! Yet any idea, on how to *avoid* the raising of that error?

Comment: If I run this in a loop (say, 500 times) I can get `OSError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable`, but still not the error you're getting. If I use the *same* multiprocessing pool for each run, I can get it to run 5000 times in a row without error.

Comment: @aganders3: Precisely, the `multiprocessing.Pool` class spawns *processes*, not *threads*. That's *exactly* why I'm asking for help here, namely because the error doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: How often/how many times are you calling your `batch_grad` function?

Comment: Sorry for help creating this huge comment thread.  Maybe the Python mailing list is a better place to ask.

Comment: @aganders3 50 times, each invocation taking about one minute.

Comment: Can you try either a) re-using the same pool for each call, and/or b) using the `Pool.close()` function after you call `Pool.map()`?

Comment: @aganders3 I will give that a try and report then, thanks!

Comment: @aganders3: I haven't experienced the error again since I added `Pool.close()` to my code. I hope that really did the trick, but I will keep an eye on that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem stems from spawning many `Pool`s. The error is strange, and I think @ChongMa is correct that it's related to the Python interpreter itself not being able to spawn a thread. It sounds like my suggestion in the comments may be working for you, so I'm reposting it here as an answer.

Try these fixes:
a) use the `Pool.close()` method to let each `Pool` know it's not going to get any more work:

```
def batch_grad(x0, y, processes=4):
    pool = Pool(processes)
    g = pool.map(UnrollArgs(grad), [(x0, yi) for yi in y])
    pool.close()
    return np.sum([gi for gi in g], axis=0) / len(y)
```

b) re-use a `Pool` for all your processing - passing the `Pool` object into your `batch_grad` function, instead of a number of processes:

```
def batch_grad(x0, y, pool=None):
    if pool is None:
        pool = Pool(4)
    g = pool.map(UnrollArgs(grad), [(x0, yi) for yi in y])
    return np.sum([gi for gi in g], axis=0) / len(y)

# then call your function like so
p = Pool(4)
batch_grad(your_x0, your_y, p)
```

Hopefully this works out for you long term.

Comment: Thanks again, I will "accept" your answer after some more testing.